# How to pass table name from global parameter in adf

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

I need to pass select query in adf for lookup dates
My query is working fine

```
SELECT [LastSuccessWatermarkDate] FROM [dbo].[arddl_WaterMarkCntrl]
WHERE SourceTable = '@{item().entity_name}'
```

but I want to pass global parameter as tablename instead of `[dbo].[arddl_WaterMarkCntrl]`

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the below logic:

```
SELECT [LastSuccessWatermarkDate] FROM @{pipeline().globalParameters.TableName}
WHERE SourceTable = '@{item().entity_name}'
```

Comment: so `TableName = dbo.arddl_WaterMarkCntrl` is that correct

Comment: i have created two parameters `dbo_parameter` and `tablename_parameter`  then how to use that

Comment: Hey @SurajShejal, To answer to your 1st query yes : TableName = dbo.arddl_WaterMarkCntrl

Can you please tell what is the meaning of your 2nd query (And what values would those hold)